# show checkbox before every contact using wrapper class

Tags: visualforce, controller, wrapper-class, inputcheckboxes, outputfield

I'm trying to fetch the contact record and showing on page using  its showing error

> Unknown property EditContact_controller.wrapperClass.conList

Which thing is unknown.

here is my controller

```
public class EditContact_controller{
    public List<wrapperClass> wrapClassList{get;set;}
    public List<contact> conList;
    public wrapperClass wc{get;set;}

    public EditContact_controller(){
        wrapClassList = new List<wrapperClass>();
        conList = new List<Contact>();
        conList = [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName FROM Contact LIMIT 10];
        For(Contact co : conList){
            wc = new wrapperClass();
            wc.flag = false;
            wc.conWrap = co;
            wrapClassList.add(wc);
        }
    }
    public class wrapperClass{
        public boolean flag{get;set;}
        public Contact conWrap{get;set;}

     }
    }
```

Here is my VFPage

```
<apex:page controller="EditContact_controller" tabStyle="Contact">
<apex:form id="frm">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Contact Records">

        <apex:repeat value="{!wrapClassList}" var="contactTable" id="cont_Table">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th> Action </th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th> First Name </th>
                </tr>

                <tr> 
                    <th> Last Name </th>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td> <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!contactTable.flag}"/> </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td> <apex:outputField value="{!contactTable.conList.FirstName}"/> </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td> <apex:outputField value="{!contactTable.conList.LastName}"/> </td>
                </tr>


            </table>           
        </apex:repeat>

    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the contact var in the wrapper is conWrap so you should use that

```
ContactTable.conWrap.FirstName
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this and use conWrap instead of conList

```
            <tr>
                <td> <apex:outputField value="{!contactTable.conWrap.FirstName}"/> </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td> <apex:outputField value="{!contactTable.conWrap.LastName}"/> </td>
            </tr>
```